# How to solve unexpected behaviour with function calls in wolframscript?

Tags: scripting, high-performance-clusters

I have the following piece of code saved as script.wls that is called using `wolframscript -file script.wls <inputs>`

```
xmlFile = $ScriptCommandLine[[2]];
dataInput = ToExpression[#] & /@ $ScriptCommandLine[[3 ;; Length[$ScriptCommandLine]]];
{derTau, inputPrec, inputcc, inputDeltaMin, inputhMin} = dataInput;

<<path/to/Virasoro_master_annulus_ders.m;
<<path/to/SDPB.m;

Print["Code started running..."]
(* This is kind of a hacky way of dealing with prec being protected in SDPB.m. Needs to be handled better *)
Unprotect[prec];
prec = inputPrec;

Print["Files imported."]
Print["Computing derivatives..."]
fulltable = computeTables[derTau, inputPrec][inputcc] 
Print["Derivatives computed."]
```

`computeTables` is a function defined in the Virasoro_master_annulus_ders.m file. The file script.wls contains more code later which uses the variable `fulltable` to perform further calculations on it but those parts do not cause any problems (see below to understand what I mean).

The problem I am facing is the following. When wolframscript is called, the file runs up to `Print["Computing derivatives..."]` and then quits. If I pass hardcoded numbers to the function call (for example `computeTables[10,100][1]`, the file runs correctly and the later parts of the code also function properly. My immediate hunch was that the variables `derTau` and so on were not being defined well. I checked for that by printing the values before the function call and I got the expected output from Print, which means that it's not a problem with the variables being undefined. To be completely sure, I wrapped the first three lines in `InitializationCell[]`, and the problem still persists. What's weirder is that doing the following runs properly

```
derTau = 10;
inputPrec = 100;
inputcc = 1;
fulltable = computeTables[derTau, inputPrec][inputcc]
```

I am unable to understand what causes the computation to fail. This behaviour was never observed before with the exact same piece of code.

Comment: Check `Head[derTau]`. Is it really `Integer` and not `String`?

Comment: @Domen yes I checked that. The head is Integer